# I have a switch theme button, on my website, how can i save the theme when refreshing, or going to an other pages?

Tags: javascript, button, cookies, switch-statement, refresh

I created a switch theme button for my website, it only modify the background color of the body and the header.

The html :

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <button onclick="SwitchTheme()"></button>
</div>
```

The js :

```
function SwitchTheme() {

                   var element = document.querySelector("body");
                   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

                   var elementB = document.querySelector("header");
                   elementB.classList.toggle("nav-dark-mode");


                   var x = document.getElementById("Sun");
                   var y = document.getElementById("Moon");

                      if (x.style.display === "none") {
                        x.style.display = "block";
                        y.style.display = "none";
                      } 

                      else {
                        x.style.display = "none";
                        y.style.display = "block";
                      }

                      console.log("VarSampleVal")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store theme a class on cookie, using javascript cookie. so that when the class name existed on the cookie use it as a default theme class.

Then everytime your page reloaded/refreshed, check on the cookie of what class is stored and print it on your class tag.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SwitchTheme() {

   var element = document.querySelector("body");
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

   var elementB = document.querySelector("header");
   elementB.classList.toggle("nav-dark-mode");


   var x = document.getElementById("Sun");
   var y = document.getElementById("Moon");

      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";

        // Store Dark Mode Class in Cookie
        document.cookie = "my_theme_body_class=dark-mode; path=/";
        document.cookie = "my_theme_header_class=nav-dark-mode; path=/";
      } 

      else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "block";


        // Delete Value Dark Mode Class in Cookie
        document.cookie = "my_theme_body_class=; path=/";
        document.cookie = "my_theme_header_class=; path=/"; 
      }

      console.log("VarSampleVal")
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

var el_body = document.querySelector("body");
el_body.classList.add(getCookie('my_theme_body_class'));

var el_header = document.querySelector("header");
el_body.classList.add(getCookie('my_theme_header_class'));
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your comment, but i tried it and it seems to not working. This is the link of my website : theohelias.fr if someone want try to fix it !